# Django: GET request is working correctly, but sending the data in the POST request is not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I sent a POST to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_ques_management/add_favorite_question/ again with this JSON body:

```
{
  "idname": "aallen",
  "question_id": 201
}
```

Got response:

```
{
    "error": "User not found."
}
```

And also got this in the terminal:
Received POST data: <QueryDict: {}>
Received idname: None
Not Found: /user_ques_management/add_favorite_question/

But when I sent a GET request with the same users user id to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_ques_management/favorite_read_questions/3486/:
I got successful response:

```
{
    "user_id": 3486,
    "display_name": "Dustin Rodriguez",
    "favorite_questions": [],
    "read_questions": []
}
```

I see the user information is there in the Database too.
Here is my model for UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    idname = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.display_name
```

Views.py for both of the urls:
View to Insert Favorite Question for a User

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_favorite_question(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Received POST data:", request.POST)
        idname = request.POST.get('idname')  # Use 'idname' instead of 'user_id'
        question_id = request.POST.get('question_id')
        print("Received idname:", idname)  # Print the received idname

        try:
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(idname=idname)
            question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)

            FavoriteQuestion.objects.create(user_id=user, question_id=question)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Favorite question added successfully.'})
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'User not found.'}, status=404)
        except Question.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Question not found.'}, status=404)
```

View to Retrieve Favorite and Read Questions for a User

```
def get_favorite_and_read_questions(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user_id)
        favorite_questions = FavoriteQuestion.objects.filter(user_id=user).values('question_id')
        read_questions = ReadQuestion.objects.filter(user_id=user).values('question_id')

        favorite_question_ids = [item['question_id'] for item in favorite_questions]
        read_question_ids = [item['question_id'] for item in read_questions]

        response_data = {
            'user_id': user.id,
            'display_name': user.display_name,
            'favorite_questions': favorite_question_ids,
            'read_questions': read_question_ids,
        }

        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'User not found.'}, status=404)
```

Why for the GET request, the user information is showing, but for the POST request, it says no user found? Also, there are dummy data I generated using Faker and later loaded to the sqlite database.

Comment: How are you sending the POST request exactly ? It seems that Django does not receive the parameters sent in the body.

Comment: I am using Postman to send the POST request. With JSON payload.

Comment: Is the body configuration in Postman correctly set a a Raw JSON ?

Maybe you can try with another API client to be sure or use another type of body payload.

Comment: Yeah the body configuration was also right. But later I found that, the request I am sending was ending in request.body. 
And that is not same as POST so, won't be in the request.POST.

Comment: That's why the POST was not retrieving any user data. I could parse the JSON data in the request body and then access the field.

But won't it be better to use DRF for handling API views, especially when I'm dealing with JSON data in POST requests?

Comment: Ah yes, request.POST is more for forms and maybe not JSON bodies. Yes DRF is the best tool to manage JSON API with Django. The data validation and auto creation of endpoints for your models are very powerful. If you have only one view maybe it's not necessary but for a complete API system you will really benefit from using it.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine. It seems like it is not receiving the request correctly. Can you also include the code for the request ? QueryDict seems empty. Plus it is very strange that you actually get the data with a get request as you are checking for the mothod. To avoid the check you can also use a decorator btw! Also

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

Comment: I actually found that, the request I am sending was ending in request.body. And that is not same as POST so, won't be in the request.POST. That's why the POST was not retrieving any user data. I could parse the JSON data in the request body and then access the field.